# If I boot into safe mode will I have root access?

Tags: root-access, safe-mode

If I am rooted and if I boot into safe mode, will I be having root access and how to test that I have root access.

Comment: @esQmo can you make it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe mode only disable users app (non system apps) and let you troubleshoot which apps may be  causing trouble.

And yes, of course you'll still have root access. The only way to check root is  via adb command.

Install ADB (now available since Google released it without all the SDK), open a terminal and tape this command :`adb shell su`
***The output should be # instead of $***

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will still have root. It will just be hard to test it, as all user apps (the only ones the use root) will be disabled.